# Jest Invariant Violation

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Simple use of [react hooks in beta](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) do not work when using jest and result in an error of

Invariant Violation: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

Despite much looking around I do not see working examples of Jest with react hooks. Yes I know it is beta but let us flag it now.

https://github.com/ghinks/jest-react-hook-issue.git

```
const MyDiv = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const clickHandler = () => { setCount(count + 1); 
  console.log(`clicked ${count}`) }
  return (
    <div onClick={clickHandler}>
      ClickMe {count}
    </div>
  )
}
```

even simple tests

```
import { MyDiv } from './App';

describe('Test Component using hooks', () => {
  test('MyDiv', () => {
    const div = MyDiv();
    expect(div).toMatchSnapshot();
  })
});
```

will fail with the invariant error.

[image: error image]

I would expect this to actually work.

Comment: apologies clone the example via https://github.com/ghinks/jest-react-hook-issue.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like simple change to

```
describe('Test Component using hooks', () => {
  test('MyDiv', () => {
    expect(<MyDiv/>).toMatchSnapshot();
  })
});
```

resolves this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what the error says. Function components aren't supposed to be called directly.

It should be as [the reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing) shows:

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

...
const myDiv = renderer.create(<MyDiv/>).toJSON();
expect(myDiv).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Comment: Many thanks I have tried this to no avail. I was actually taking a working site with functional components and attempting to use the beta stage react hooks and came across the error. I'm happy for you to raise a PR against it if you are certain.

Comment: What exactly does 'no avail' means? Hooks are alpha, not beta. It's the same as with other React packages. You likely need matching `react-test-renderer` version, i.e. 16.7.0-alpha.2. Notice that 16.7.0 release doesn't contain hooks, https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/12/19/react-v-16-7.html

Comment: sincere thanks Estus, apologies 'no avail' is just a super polite way of saying it
did not work. I did push up a branch taking the suggestions you had on board.

https://github.com/ghinks/jest-react-hook-issue/tree/solution/proposal-one-test-renderer

I get the same error, I think this is a little bit deeper in that the hooks do not seem
to work in the test.  

I would be absolutely delighted for you to make a PR against this branch
to get it to work.

Comment: I mean that it could not work for many reasons. Is the error still `Invariant Violation`? From the repo, I see that you didn't follow the suggestion to use `react-test-renderer@16.7.0-alpha.2`. Again, **it won't work with react-test-renderer@16.7.0**. I believe that's the reason why the error persists. Sadly, I'm currently unable to check that it makes tests workable and do a PR.

Comment: Did it work for you? Consider marking the answer as answered if it did, this may help other users.